# HTML question for an automatic save/timed save

Tags: javascript, html, json, filemaker

I'm not familiar with html at all and am a little stuck. I have the following code to stick in a FileMaker database program and would like to convert the custom button to a timed function that happens every 1 or 2 seconds say.
Or even... if there was a way to query the function from FileMaker so I could put a button (a send button) in the FileMaker database as the user would prefer that as a layout.

nb - I've commented out some buttons as I'm not sure if I'm using them yet.

Thanks in advance!

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML Editor</title>
    <!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- include summernote css/js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.16/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
    <!--  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.16/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="summernote">[[CONTENT]]</div>
<script>

    // add a 'Save' button to the toolbar
    var SaveButton = function (context) {
        var ui = $.summernote.ui;

        // create button
        var button = ui.button({
            contents: 'Send',
            tooltip: 'Save changes',
            click: function () {
                //$('#summernote').summernote('code', 'code');
                //window.alert('save changes');
                /* Prep the URL to use for the hand-off to FM. */
                var fullURL = '[[SAVEURL]]&param=' + encodeURIComponent ($('#summernote').summernote('code'));
                /* Send the data to FM. */
                window.location = fullURL;
                return false;
            }
        });
        return button.render();   // return button as jquery object 
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote({
            height: 300,
            tabsize: 2,
            toolbar: [
                // [groupName, [list of button]]
                ['style', ['style','bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                //['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
                //['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                //['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                //['height', ['height']],
                ['insert', ['link']],
                //['insert', ['link','hr','table']],
                //['misc',['codeview']],
                ['mybutton',['save']]
            ],
            buttons: {save: SaveButton}
        });
    });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `setInterval` of js to repeat the function in every x seconds

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: Ah! Okay - this stops typing after every call... removes the cursor.